# Audio recognition from a video

Tags: rest, audio-recording, audio-analysis

I need to know the exact timeframe location from a Video using a small part of the audio. I will prefer using an external api, using google, amazon or Microsoft Voice/Audio solutions. Anyone knows what can I use? thanks.

Comment: Could you make your question more specific?

Comment: I need to do a mobile app that can listen the audio of a video (from a tv or computer) every 10 second (for example), then I'll need to send that audio to the server and be able to know the exact time/timeframe in the video. I will have the source of the videos.  I will like to know if I can use something like Microsoft Video Indexing, or Google Video apis, or Amazon Videos/Audio api, or something else. Thanks.

Comment: what is the final use-case/solution you are trying to achieve ?